# Assign variable value in javascript and use in html

Tags: javascript, html

How to assign a variable value in `javascript` and use it in `html`?

My `javascript` code:

```
function validateUrl() {
    var displayButton = "Yes";
}
```

My `html` code:

```
<c:if test="${displayButton == 'Yes' "
</c:if>
```

How can i use a `javsacript` variable in  my `html`?

Comment: you could not do like this. Which technical language you are using like .net, php or JAVA ?

Comment: if you want to use dynamic  value in html, you need to use either any scripting language like php,java,C#, etc... or you need to use the front end  jsframework like Angular.js, knockout.js etc..

Comment: Have you invented that `<c:if>` tag yourself, or is there some templating system which actually handles that? If so the problem simply becomes *when* Javascript executes and *when* the template is parsed. Usually Javascript executes after templates are parsed, soooo... no.

Answer (score 1):

This is not HTML, it is a JSTL-Tag.

The code `<c:if` will be evaluated by the server (glassfish/tomcat) while producing the HTML which will be provided to the browser.

The JavaScript code runs in the browser.
There is no (simple) way to use JavaScript values to manipulate HTML-rendering.

HTML itself isn't able to work with JavaScript-variables, so the only way is, to set a variable in JavaScript and use the value with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can set data using jquery and `$("#display-button").data("key", "Yes")` you can read the data out using `$("#dispaly-button").data("key") -> returns "Yes"`

Comment: how to use in if condition ?

Comment: this way only works if you use JavaScript to manipulate your HTML the mentioned method can be used only on the client site to store data in HTML..